# Python moving files and directories from one folder to another

Tags: python

I would like to move in python files and directories in one directory to another directory with overwrite ability.

I started with the following code:

```
        #moving files from progs
        path = tempfolder + 'progs/'
        for dirs,files in os.listdir(path):
                 for f in files:
                        shutil.move(os.path.join(path, f) , os.path.join(compteurfolder, f))
```

So for the moment, I only try to move the files and I get the following errors:

```
    for dirs,files in os.listdir(path):
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I guess this is because I have dirs and files but then how will I move directories too? And how to make sure it can overwrite the files in the other folder?

Hope you can help.

Comment: The exception is simple. You are asking for two values: dirs and files. While listdir will return only one list with dirs and files. You will have to seperate them within the forloop.

Comment: So, if you have `progs/spam/eggs.txt` and `target/spam/beans.txt`, you want to overwrite `target/spam` with `progs/spam`, losing `beans.txt` entirely, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason this fails:

```
for dirs,files in os.listdir(path):
```

… is that `os.listdir` just returns a list of filenames. So, each element is a string, and you're trying to unpack that string into two variables. Compare this:

```
a, b = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
for a, b in [(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), (9, 10)]
dirs, files = "spam.txt"
for dirs, files in ["spam.txt", "eggs.dat"]
```

It's the exact same error in every case—you can't fit 8 things into 2 variables.

Meanwhile, if `listdir` is just returning filenames, how do you know ones are the names of regular files, are which are the names of directories? You have to ask—e.g., by using `isdir`.

So:

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if os.path.isdir(filename):
        # do directory stuff
    else:
        # do regular file stuff
```

(But note that this can still be confusing if you have symlinks…)

---

Meanwhile, what does "do regular file stuff" mean?

Well, assuming you don't have a directory (or a symlink to a directory) with the same name as the file you're trying to move there, as the docs for [`shutil.move`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) say, `os.rename` or `shutil.copy2` will be used. If you're not on Windows, this is perfect—if you have permission to overwrite the target you will, otherwise you'll get a permissions error. But if you *are* on Windows, [`os.rename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename) will fail if the target already exists.

If you're on 3.3 or later, you can solve this by copying the [`shutil.move` source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/shutil.py#l490)* and using `os.replace` instead, as the `rename` docs imply. Otherwise, you will have to delete the target before renaming the source.

<sub>* Some stdlib modules—including `shutil`—are meant to serve as sample code as well as usable helpers. In those cases, at the top of the module's docs, there will be a **Source code:** link.</sub>

---

And what about "do directory stuff"? Well, if you move a directory `spam` to a target `eggs/spam`, and `eggs/spam` already exists as a directory, you're going to end up moving to `eggs/spam/spam`.

This shouldn't be surprising, as it's exactly the same thing `mv` on Unix and `move` on Windows do, which is what `shutil` is trying to simulate.

So, what you need to do here is delete the target (this time using `shutil.rmtree`) before moving the source.

---

Which means the simplest thing to do may be to not distinguish files and directories, Windows and Unix, or anything else; just do this:

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    target = os.path.join(compteurfolder, filename)
    try:
        shutil.rmtree(target)
    except NotADirectoryError:
        try:
            os.unlink(target)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass
    shutil.move(os.path.join(path, filename), target)
```

Comment: I used your first part as I am not using symlink and it works great. Really thank you for your help...

Comment: The problem with this is that it will remove the all the contents of the target dir.  This is not the intended operation for a move. 

A better solution would move the files to the target directory, without removing the entire target first.  Takes a bit more code, but it is a much more preferable solution.

Answer (score 0):

This because os.listdir(path) return array according documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html). So you should modify you code as following for moving files and directories.

```
    #moving files from progs
    path = tempfolder + 'progs/'
    for item_path in os.listdir(path):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(path, item_path) , os.path.join(compteurfolder, item_path)
```

Comment: What about his seccond question?

Comment: this makes no sense, what is `for f in files`?

Comment: still won't work, you are trying to iterate over a file

Comment: You're also calling `isdir` on the wrong path. (Not surprising; using variables named `path` and `_path` is pretty confusing…)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Worse, it may "work" but silently do the wrong thing, because he's iterating over a filename, which will give him one character at a time…

Comment: If you actually read the docs for `shutil.move`, it explains that there _is_ a difference for files and directories.

Comment: @Phoenix: And that's not what `shutil.move` does with an existing directory; it moves the source _into_ the target directory, instead of overwriting the target directory. So, an answer that says "I guess there is not difference for files and directories" is just going to mislead.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import os
>>> import shutil

>>> for node in os.listdir(path):
...      if not os.path.isdir(node):
...          shutil.move(os.path.join(path, node) , os.path.join(compteurfolder, node))
```

Comment: Don't you have also to import `shutil`
, by the way?

Answer (score -2):

(Python 3.6)
From a previous answer (can't add comment)

I think that the line

```
if not os.path.isdir(node):
```

Should read

```
if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(source, node))
```

Otherwise it will always return `True` and move the sub folders as well.

```
>>> import os
>>> import shutil

>>> for node in os.listdir(path):
...      if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, node)):
...          shutil.move(os.path.join(path, node) , os.path.join(compteurfolder, node))
```