# shutil.move deleted all my photos

Tags: python, move, photo, shutil

```
for i in os.listdir():
   if "jpeg" in i or "png" in i:
      shutil.move(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),i),"my photos")
```

I wanted to move all photos to a folder called "my photos" which is not exist. It created a txt file called "my photos" but it is just 300 kb and when I quickview it it only shows one of my photo. So how can I get my photos back? where are they now?

Comment: I'm afraid that all your photos have been moved on the same file, the next one overwriting the previous one. So you only have the last photo available. Don't do anything more on your disk, use a disk recovery software to try to recover them (like Stellar NTFS recovery if you're running windows)

Comment: Oops.. Well, that's why you have t debug first with dummy input. To do what you wanted to do, the second argument of `shutil.move` should have been an existing directory. So you should have created the folder first.. So it was interpreted as a file which was being overwriten every time a new photo was being moved. I think you lost em mate..

Comment: I am using mac so is there any recovery software to recover them? I did not know it has to be an existing file. I learned but it cost me my photos :(

Answer (score 1):

I believe `shutil.move` simply took each file and interpreted "my photos" as the name to save each file as rather than a directory to copy it into. For each image in the directory, it would have overwritten it, leaving "my photos" with just the contents of the last image copied.

Looking at examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27545642/1636276) of how people have used `shutil` for moving files, they join the base directory name and the file name to form the `target` parameter.

I hope you had backups.