# Renaming directory of image files with consecutive numbers

Tags: python

I have 900 image files (all png, jpg, or gif). I'm trying to write a quick code that will take each image file and rename it to a number from 1-900 (the order doesn't matter, just that they're each unique). My attempt is below:

## renamer.py

```
"""Rename directory of image files with consecutive numbers"""
#Importing - os to make array of files and rename, Image to check file type
import os
from PIL import Image

#Variables for script
images_dir = "C:\file\directory\pictures\\temp\\"
file_array = os.listdir(images_dir)
file_name = 1

#Loops through each file and renames it to either a png or gif file
for file in file_array:
    img = Image.open(images_dir + file)
    if img.format != "GIF":
        os.rename(images_dir + file, images_dir + str(file_name) + ".png")
    elif img.format == "GIF":
        os.rename(images_dir + file, images_dir + str(file_name) + ".gif")
    file_name = file_name + 1
```

So far, this isn't working at all. I had tried something else before - actually opening the file with Image from PIL, saving it under the desired name, and deleting the original - but that would always fail somewhere at about 700, so I opted for this method; it seems much more efficient anyways. I'm using PyCharm and the error I'm getting is:

> C:\Python27\python.exe "renamer.py"
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "renamer.py", line 15, in
>
> ```
> os.rename(images_dir + file, images_dir + str(file_name) + ".png")
> ```
>
> WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it
> is being used by another process
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I'm not sure what the error means or how to troubleshoot from here. Any tips? I'd also love to see what other/more efficient ways some of you can come up with to do this.

Comment: Don't forget to make backups first; [some guy a few days ago](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41637906/1636276) ended up losing all of his images trying to perform bulk operations on image files.

Comment: I would recommend rather than concatenating directory and file name using `+`, that you use `os.path.join` function. Also if you are still in testing phase, maybe you shouldn't be modifying the actual names of the images, and instead should create copies of them and within the program, then modify those copies and delete the copies appropriately. The most likely cause for the error is that you opened the image using pillow; Try closing this file before performing the renaming

Comment: It could be that you have opened the file `Image.open(images_dir + file)`. I don't seen the need to do so anyway, just check if the filename ends with that format or split the extension and check it.

Comment: Thanks for the warning! I am indeed copying the files over safely to a temporary folder while I fool around with them.

Comment: @StevenSummers It's possible that the image is a gif or png file without it being saved with those extensions, though. Perhaps that is a case OP is considering.

Comment: Note that if any of the old files already have names that match the names produced by your code then they will get over-written if they haven't yet been renamed themselves.

Comment: You say that the files are all png, jpg, or gif, but your code only handles PNG and GIF; it'd rename any non-GIF files to `.png`!

Comment: @StevenSummers What Tagc said. From the look of the OP's code, it _appears_ that these files currently don't have _any_ extension.

Comment: BTW, you can get rid of that `if` by using `'.' + img.format.lower()` as the extension.

Comment: @Tagc, and PM 2Ring, my files did all have extensions - either png, jpg, or gif. For the sake of this code, I just split them up into "not gif" or "gif", and renamed all "not gif" as png, since I don't think that will do too much damage to the jpg files (and I like png more), so yeah, I guess I didn't have to use PIL at all. I appreciate all the tips!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Image.open()` opens the image and reads its header, but still holds the file opened, so the operating system can't rename it.

Try `del img` before renaming, or try `img.load()` to force loading the data and releasing hold of the image file.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the problem! Both your solution, and @Steven Summers' solution of foregoing the use of Image worked!